# Adding OAuth Server Support to PyroCMS / Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, oauth, pyrocms

I am looking for a way to extend PyroCMS into an OAuth2.0 server. I want my users to be able to log onto my "customer" websites using a central authentication system.

I looked into https://github.com/alexbilbie/CodeIgniter-OAuth-2.0-Server but I am having trouble in planning how to integrate this with PyroCMS. I don't want to touch the core authentication so I am thinking of building a module that does this ontop of current authentication system.

Any tips/ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that there is already an OAuth module for pyrocms [here](https://github.com/pyrocms/social)

which covers OAuth 1 and OAuth 2.0

Comment: That allows users to authenticate against other oauth providers. I want to do implement the reverse. Allow other apps to authenticate against pyrocms.